# How to inflect prepositional time expressions?

Tags: time, inflection

> Am 17. Oktober 1993

*17* in the date above will be *siebzente**n**.* What about *1993?* Can you please write the date above without using ciphers.

Comment: It might help you to remember that dates in German (and English) for a long time were relative expressions. That means that days were designated as relative to some fixed points in time: "Twenty days after Christmas Eve", "One week before the day of St. Peter" and so on. That still shows in todays language. "17. Oktober 1993" means "the seventeenth day of the month Oktober of the year 1993", in German "der siebzehnte Tag im Monat Oktober im Jahr 1993". Therefore, the day is expressed as an ordinal number, while month and year are not.

Comment: Good note. It will help me to remember it. Thank you

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: Was ist mit dem siebten Tag des zehnten Monats des 1993ten Jahres unserer Zeitrechnung?

Comment: Es gibt Formulierungen wie "der 17. 10.", gesprochen "der Siebzehnte Zehnte" oder "der siebzehnte Tag des zehnten Monats". Das funktioniert aber nicht, wenn der Eigenname des Monats genannt wird. "der Siebzehnte Oktobere" oder ähnlich wäre also falsch. Das Jahr als Ordinalzahl ist meiner Erfahrung nach, wenn es überhaupt vorkommt, sehr selten. Ich würde vermuten, weil ein oder gar viele Jahre für die meisten Menschen ein schwerer zu überblickender Zeitraum ist, im Gegensatz zu etwa "dreißig Tage vor Johanni".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using numbers the date reads as follows:

> am siebzehnten Oktober neunzehnhundertdreiundneunzig

Comment: So 17 is ordinal number here and has adjectival ending while 1993 is cardinal and therefore completely unaffected by preposition, right?

Comment: That's not all to it. There also the question of case in different writing  contexts, see http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Ordinal.html?lang=en